# Matlab ode solver using the time in a function for 'value' in events

Tags: function, matlab, events, time, ode

I've searched extensively, and thought I wouldn't be the only one having this problem, but it seems to look like I am.

I am solving an ode via ode15s (my problem can be stiff) and I use the 'Events' option to find my point of interest.
The problem is: the equation that I use in 'value' is depending (among other things) on the specific time (so value = f(t,y,y'), and I cannot find a way of passing the current time to this function, only the y vector is available.

Anyone has any ideas?
Thanks in advance and all the enjoy the rest of your holidays!

Comment: If i read it correctly, events takes both t and y as input, so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, made a really stupid error (used , instead of ;)...

You can just use the t argument as long as you set it in your @odefunction(t,y) as well as your @events(t,y).